# Is PHP ldap_escape compatible with Microsoft Active Directory?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Here

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx

you can see how AD requires to escape individual components of a distinguished name (a backslash in front of the character to be escaped).

The [ldap_escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-escape.php) function, however, adopts a different escaping technique (I think according to [RFC4514](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4514)) so for example:

Sales\Engineering would be:

Sales\\Engineering according to [1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx)

and:

Sales\5cEngineering if you use [ldap_escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-escape.php)

I know that \5c is just the \xx hex sequence for \, but can this create problems?

I am having troubles using [ldap_bind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php) with domain\user DNs in Active Directory that's why I am wondering if there are compatibility issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> domain\user DNs in Active Directory

I think this may be a misunderstanding. The `DOMAIN\username` format is not a distinguished name. Even if you did use a proper DN there, the `$dn` parameter of `ldap_bind` does not require any escaping.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx) refers to different scenarios where you may need to escape characters. The first section refers to escaping characters in a component of a distinguished name. A distinguished name would look something like this:

```
CN=SomeUser,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

A character might need escaping in a distinguished name if the name of the object (the `CN` portion) uses a character that is a special character in the DN format, like `,`, `=`, `\`, etc. Which could look something like this:

```
CN=Luci\, Gabriel,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

But in those cases, the escaping is already done for you. The `\,` is part of the actual DN of the object. So you'll never find a need to escape a DN of an existing object.

The only time you would need to escape characters that would be part of a DN is if you're creating a new object and need to prepare a string to be the name of the new object. However, `ldap_escape` doesn't escape like this, even when using `LDAP_ESCAPE_DN`. This seems to come down to [RFC2253](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2253), which gives two options for escaping characters:

> If a character to be escaped is one of the list shown above, then it is prefixed by a backslash ('' ASCII 92).
>
> Otherwise the character to be escaped is replaced by a backslash and two hex digits, which form a single byte in the code of the character.

Active Directory seems to prefer the first, whereas `ldap_escape` with `LDAP_ESCAPE_DN` uses the second method. It might actually work with AD, but I haven't tested it.

The Microsoft documentation also describes escaping values for use [in an LDAP filter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx#LDAP_Filters), which is done differently. This seems to be the only use case for `ldap_escape`. Characters that are allowed elsewhere (like in a DN) have special meaning in an LDAP query, like `(`, `)`, `\`, etc.

```
$escapedValue = ldap_escape("Luci, Gabriel (Company)", null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER);
// resulting value will be "Luci, Gabriel \28Company\29"
$query = "(&objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(cn={$escapedValue}))";
```

That's where the `\5c` that you're seeing is coming from. That's only needed for LDAP filters, which isn't what you need there.

You don't need to escape anything when providing a user account as credentials.

Comment: What I meant was actually DOMAIN\sAMAccount or probably we can say SUBTREE\sAMAccount. The bind with ldap_bind perfectly works, it stops working if I use ldap_escape.

Comment: Apart from that, even using a DN such as  CN=SomeUser,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com the doubt remains: the MS page I posted mentions an escape approach that is different from the one ldap_escape provides.

Comment: @Eugenio Sorry, I hadn't finished my morning coffee yet. I misunderstood the purpose of `ldap_bind`. I know AD, but I'm more of a C# guy than PHP. I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel what you said makes sense but only if you know the DN in advance. In my system, the user fill a login form with username and password and then I concat the username part with the base DN or use the backslash syntax I mentioned. The point is that the user doesn't know the "escaped" version of their username (or CN or sAMAccount whatever you are using). Probably I could just escape that part (username) but the general problem still remains, is ldap_escape compatible with AD? It doesn't do what MS describes in the page I posted.

Comment: `ldap_escape` does do what the MS documentation describes. But you only need to do it in the two scenarios I describe in my answer (creating a new object, or in an LDAP filter). You don't need to use `ldap_escape` with `ldap_bind`. You can give `ldap_bind` the format `DOMAIN\username` without escaping.

Comment: I think you have to use it in the username as well if it contains characters to be escaped. But let's focus on ldap_add and ldap_search if you prefer: why do you say ldap_escape does what the MS documentation describes: in my post I showed an example where the output is different.

Comment: I did some testing myself, and I think I see what you mean. `ldap_escape` only seems capable of escaping characters for use in an LDAP filter, [which the MS documentation does describe](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx#LDAP_Filters). It's different than what's needed in a DN. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Eugenio Ok, I did some more reading and figured out why the difference. I updated my answer again.

Comment: I see, so for those characters both the methods should be valid but I am not sure if the second one works with AD, from my tests it seemed it doesn't but I might miss something because I am not directly testing this. I would accept your answer but again, I think it is not true that during binding you don't need escaping. Let's say for example that your samaccountname starts with a blank space, I think it does require escaping then

Comment: When you're providing credentials, like in `ldap_bind`, you'll never need to escape anything, even if there are spaces. Give it a try.

Comment: I can't test it right now but I will do it as soon as I can